# Keras Scaled-Dot Attention Model Value Error

Tags: keras, attention-model

I am trying to create a Scaled Dot Attention model using keras utility layer collection found at https://github.com/zimmerrol/keras-utility-layer-collection. I am using the default model (code below) provided in the examples notebook in the github repo. My problem is I get the following error :

> ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer model_1: expected
> shape=(None, 500, 3), found shape=(500, 3)

The code is below

```
# input: time series with 500 steps
# each step has a 3dim valuethe output sequences
# of a LSTM, RNN, etc.
net_input = Input(shape=(500, 3))
net = TimeDistributed(Dense(3))(net_input)

# queries
net_q = TimeDistributed(Dense(3))(net_input)
# values
net_v = TimeDistributed(Dense(3))(net_input)
# keys
net_k = TimeDistributed(Dense(3))(net_input)

# add one ScaledDotProductAttention layer
net = attention.ScaledDotProductAttention(name="attention", return_attention=False)([net_q, net_v, net_k])

net_output = TimeDistributed(Dense(2))(net)

model = Model(inputs=net_input, outputs=net_output)
model.summary()
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics='accuracy')

# dummy data
# x = np.random.rand(64, 500, 3)
# y = np.random.rand(64, 500, 2)
# X, y = make_multilabel_classification(n_samples=500, n_features=3, n_classes=3, n_labels=2, random_state=1)
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=500, n_features=3, n_redundant=0, n_repeated=0, n_informative=3,
                           n_classes=3, random_state=1)

print(X.shape, y.shape)
model.fit(X, y, batch_size=500, epochs=1)
```

EDIT :
The summary of the model is also added below

```
Model: "model"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_2 (InputLayer)            [(None, 500, 3)]     0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_5 (TimeDistrib (None, 500, 3)       12          input_2[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_6 (TimeDistrib (None, 500, 3)       12          input_2[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_7 (TimeDistrib (None, 500, 3)       12          input_2[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
attention (ScaledDotProductAtte (None, 500, 3)       0           time_distributed_5[0][0]         
                                                                 time_distributed_6[0][0]         
                                                                 time_distributed_7[0][0]         
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_8 (TimeDistrib (None, 500, 2)       8           attention[0][0]                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 44
Trainable params: 44
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You are missing the samples dimension, i.e. (N, 500, 3), where N is the number of samples.

Comment: Any idea on how to modify the code to add that? I cannot simply pass None to the input shape, i.e. do `net_input = Input(shape=(None, 500, 3))`

Comment: The problem is not in your model, its in your data, it should have the samples dimension.